# Does the quality of USB cable affect the power drawn?

Tags: power, cables, usb-device, output, testing

I was wondering how the power drawn is affected by different cable? I tested two different types: A USB cable plugged to a USB digital tester which showed a power of **4.88 V** and **2A** drawn, whereas the other cable (*around similar length*) was drawing **5 V** and **0.8A** around **5 Watts** for the same load. Why is that so?

Comment: Two cables, plugged into a tester, with what load attached? Is the tester acting as the load, or the source? Does it negotiate power draw using the USB spec?

Comment: A cable shouldn't use any power. It's the device on the other end that does that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe only a little about quality but most likely you just have two cables intended for two completely different purposes.

Most likely one of your USB cables allows the load (whatever that is) to communicate with the supply (whatever that is) how much it can draw current. And the other cable may be without data connections for charging flashlights or something. We don't know what cables you have and what connections they have inside.

Comment: That makes sense. So both cable are USB type A input and at output its USB Micro B. One is a brand name called "Insignia" which is the one able to communicate. The other cable is no brand. Does that means that mean the cable might be missing the data communication wires? Can we confirm that anyhow?

Comment: You can use a multimeter to detect continuity. Or plug it between a computer and some other device which should appear as connected on computer, like a mobile phone or something. If the devices don't communicate, either the cable has broken data wires or it is a charge-only cable with no data wires to begin with.